# How do I make the HTML Slider with CSS stay in the box?

Tags: css, rotation, webkit, slider

I have this table/slider error, but I'm not sure how to fix it to stay in the table:
http://jsfiddle.net/WH7Kf/1/
My CSS is:

```
input[type='range']{
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    border-bottom: #333 1px solid;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

My HTML5 is:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>VOLUME</td>
    <td>TONE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>volume:<input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step=".1"></td>
    <td><input id="tone" type="range" min="40" max="17000" step="1">    //seekslider</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I just figured out the basic vertical alignment, but it extends outside the box as shown: http://jsfiddle.net/WH7Kf/13/  What's wrong with HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the table, then turn the words last:
http://jsfiddle.net/WH7Kf/14/

```
table{
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}

input[type='range']{
            position: relative;
            -webkit-appearance: none !important;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            background: #000;
            height: 100px;
            width: 400px;
            border-bottom: #333 1px solid;
        }

        input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
            -webkit-appearance: none !important;
            background: radial-gradient(#FFF, #333);
            height:110px;
            width:15px;
            border-radius:100%;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried fiddling with the code and initially I thought that the slider's height would be a problem but then i realised it was the width. Use this and change the width as you wish (not 400px).

```
    input[type='range']{
        -webkit-appearance: none !important;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background: #000;
        height: 100px;
        width: 200px;
        border-bottom: #333 1px solid;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
```

Comment: You want longer toolbar so that you can control the numbers more accurately, and they al look the same (i.e. 40-17000 tone frequency ranges).

Comment: got it to work, but I need to rotate the text back: http://jsfiddle.net/WH7Kf/14/